# Centering a floated image in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript code and it needs to place images in different heights in a certein div according to the code. However, I also need the images to be centered. I searched the web and found different solutions such as using `display:inline-block` instead of `float`, but then the different heights don't work. Nothing I found seems to do the trick.

Here's the Javascript code that generates the final tags, `margin_top` is the variable that has the height difference needed.

```
var added_tags = ('<img style="margin-top:'+ margin_top.toString() +'px; float:left; margin-left:5px;" src="[Image source]" /> '+'<a></a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't center floated elements. `display: inline-block` on the to-be-centered elements and `text-align: center` on their container is the way to go.

Concerning vertical alignment of different heights, you can use `vertical-align: middle` or `top` or `bottom` on the inline-block elements, whatever you need.

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap>img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/fa0">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x70/a0f">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180/af0">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x120/f7a">
</div>
```

OR

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap>img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/fa0">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x70/a0f">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180/af0">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x120/f7a">
</div>
```

OR

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap>img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/fa0">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x70/a0f">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180/af0">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x120/f7a">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you must use floated element the desired result can be acheived:

```css
 section {
      padding:20px;
      margin:20px;
      border:1px solid silver; 
      box-sizing:border-box;
 }

 span {
      float:right;
 }

 section.centre span {
      margin-right:50%;
      transform:translateX(50%);
 }
```

```html
 <section>
      <span>ALPHA</span>
      <br style="clear:both;" />
 </section>

 <section class="centre">
      <span>BRAVO</span>
      <br style="clear:both;" />
 </section>
```

Comment: The purpose of floating an element is to have it move to the left or right. Trying to "achieve" anything else doesn't make sense using float. Also, the `<br>` does not use a closing slash and should never be used for styling (as in clearing floats).